# How to implement TOTP authentication that is compatible with java and objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, one-time-password, totp

I have a problem with TOTP authentification.

My server (java) generates a secret key and transmits it to my android and
ios applications. At the time of authentication, my mobile application runs the TOTP algorithm, taking the secret key as parameter and sending the result to the server. The server also takes this secret key and executes the TOTP algorithm and checks if the result is identical. My current problem is that the java-side algorithm returns a different result from the iOS-rated algorithm (objective-c). Do you have an algorithm running on both sides or a solution to be able to have an identical result please?

Comment: Share some code or names of libraries please.

Comment: I use this implementation : "https://github.com/shashankvaibhav/TOTPImplementationIOS/tree/master/TOTP/Classes" but I can not find a compatible algo in java.

Comment: I changed the implementation and that solved my problem : https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/tree/master/mobile/ios

Comment: What is the library you used for java server side